# Is there any identity for $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\tan(x+ka) $??

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I found this series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\tan\left(\theta+\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)=−n\cot\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}+n\theta\right)
$$
but it's not what I need.

Comment: In GeoGebra, I made $n$ a manipulable integer and $a$ a manipulable real. Playing around, the graphs on $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\tan(x+ka)$ do not appear to be anything as simple as say the right-hand side of this other identity you have found.

Answer (score 3):

**Lemma 1:**

> let $x_{j}=e^{i(2a+\frac{j-1}{n}\cdot 2\pi)}$,then we have
>   $$\dfrac{1}{1+x_{1}}+\dfrac{1}{1+x_{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{1+x_{n}}=\dfrac{n}{1+(-1)^{n-1}e^{2ina}}$$

**Proof:**

> First we note
>   $$\dfrac{1}{1+x_{1}}+\dfrac{1}{1+x_{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{1+x_{n}}=\dfrac{n+(n-1)\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}+(n-2)\sum_{i,j}x_{i}x_{j}+\cdots+\sum_{i_{1},\cdots,i_{n-1}}x_{i_{1}}x_{i_{2}}\cdots x_{i_{n-1}}}{\prod_{j=1}^{n}(1+x_{j})}$$
>   and
>   since 
>   $$x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}\cdots x_{n}=e^{i(2na+\dfrac{1+2+\cdots+n-1}{n}\cdot 2\pi)}=e^{2ina+(n-1)i\pi}=(-1)^{n-1}e^{2ina}$$
>   so I
>    note
>   $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}$ is equation roots
>   $$z^n=e^{2na\cdot i}$$
>   because
>   $$x^n_{j}=\left(e^{i(2a+\frac{(j-1)\pi}{n}}\right)^n=e^{2ina+(j-1)2\pi}=e^{2ina},j=1,2,\cdots,n$$
>   so use [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)
>   $$\begin{cases}
> \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}=0\\
> \sum_{i,j}x_{i}x_{j}=0\\
> \sum_{i,j,k}x_{i}x_{j}x_{k}=0\\
> \cdots\cdots\\
> x_{1}x_{2}\cdots x_{n}=(-1)^n\cdot (-e^{2ina})=(-1)^{n-1}e^{2ina}
> \end{cases}$$
>   so
>   $$\dfrac{1}{1+x_{1}}+\dfrac{1}{1+x_{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{1+x_{n}}=\dfrac{n+0}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+x_{i})}$$
>   By the other hand
>   $$z^n-e^{2ina}=(z-x_{1})(z-x_{2})\cdots (z-x_{n})$$
>   let $z=-1$,so
>   $$(1+x_{1})(1+x_{2})\cdots(1+x_{n})=1+(-1)^{n-1}e^{2ina}$$
>   so
>   $$\dfrac{1}{1+x_{1}}+\dfrac{1}{1+x_{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{1+x_{n}}=\dfrac{n}{1+(-1)^{n-1}e^{2ina}}$$

**Lemma 2:**
$$\dfrac{n}{i}-\dfrac{2}{i}\cdot\dfrac{n}{1+(-1)^{n-1}e^{2ina}}=-n\cot{\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{2}+na\right)}$$
**Proof:**
since
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{n}{i}-\dfrac{2}{i}\cdot\dfrac{n}{1+(-1)^{n-1}e^{2ina}}&=\dfrac{n}{i}\left(1-\dfrac{2}{1+(-1)^{n-1}e^{2ina}}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{n}{i}\cdot\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}e^{2ina}-1}{1+(-1)^{n-1}e^{2ina}}\\
&=n\cdot\dfrac{\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\cdot e^{ina}-e^{-ina}}{2i}}{\frac{e^{-ina}+(-1)^{n-1}e^{ina}}{2}}\\
&=-n\cot{\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{2}+na\right)}
\end{align*}

since
$$\tan{x}=\dfrac{1}{i}\dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}=\dfrac{1}{i}\left(1-\dfrac{2}{e^{2ix}+1}\right)$$
let
$x=a+\dfrac{(j-1)\pi}{n},j=1,2,3,\cdots,n)$,then we have
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n}\tan{(a+\dfrac{j-1}{n}\pi)}=\dfrac{n}{i}-\dfrac{2}{i}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{e^{i(2a+\frac{j-1}{n}\cdot 2\pi)}+1}$$
let
$x_{j}=e^{i(2a+\frac{j-1}{n}\cdot 2\pi)}$,

Use this **Lemma1,2**,we have
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n}\tan{(a+\dfrac{j-1}{n}\pi)}=\dfrac{n}{i}-\dfrac{2}{i}\cdot\dfrac{n}{1+(-1)^{n-1}e^{2ina}}=-n\cot{\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{2}+na\right)}$$