# The Distribution of Abscissae and Sums of Weights in Gaussian Quadrature

Tags: inequality, numerical-methods, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials, quadrature

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$, let
$x_i$ be the $i^\text{th}$ abscissa for $n$-point Gaussian
quadrature, and $w_i$ the associated weight, so that $-1 < x_1 <
x_2 < \cdots < x_n < 1$, $x_{n-i+1} = -x_i$, $w_{n-i+1} = w_i > 0$,
and $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i = 2$.

It is natural to wonder if the right-hand side of the numerical integration formula:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,dx \bumpeq \sum_{i=1}^n w_if(x_i)
\end{equation*}
(this is exact when $f$ is a polynomial of degree less than $2n$) is
a Riemann sum.

That is, if we define $s_i = \sum_{k=1}^i w_k - 1$ ($i = 0, 1,
\ldots, n$), so that $w_i = s_i - s_{i-1}$ ($i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$),
and $-1 = s_0 < s_1 < s_2 < \cdots < s_{n-1} < s_n = 1$, and
$s_{n-i} = -s_i$ ($i = 0, 1, \ldots, n$), do we have $x_i \in
[s_{i-1}, s_i]$ ($i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$)?

Indeed, we do.  As is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2600962),
$$
s_0 < x_1 < s_1 < x_2 < s_2 < \cdots < s_{n-1} < x_n < s_n.
$$
An illustration, for $n = 1$ to $9$:
[image: Abscissae and "endpoints" for Gaussian quadrature, $n = 1, 2, \ldots, 9$.]

The picture becomes clearer if we work in terms of $y_i = (2/\pi)\sin^{-1}(x_i)$
and $t_i = (2/\pi)\sin^{-1}(s_i)$.

We have $y_{n-i+1} = -y_i$ ($i =
1, 2, \ldots, n$), $t_{n-i} = -t_i$ ($i = 0, 1, \ldots, n$), and:
$$
-1 = t_0 < y_1 < t_1 < y_2 < t_2 < \cdots < t_{n-1} < y_n < t_n = 1.
$$
A pattern is visible when one displays the subintervals
$[t_{i-1}, t_i]$ with the interior points $y_i$ aligned vertically.
For $n = 64$:
[image: $y_i \in (t_{i-1}, t_i)$ ($i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$), for $n = 64$.]

If we define $u_i = y_i - t_{i-1} = t_{n-i+1} - y_{n-i+1}$ ($i =
1, 2, \ldots, n$), then $\sum_i u_i = (t_n - t_0)/2 = 1$, and the
following approximation seems surprisingly accurate:
$$
u_i \bumpeq \frac{1}{2n + 1}\left(
2 + \frac{1}{n\tan(\pi\eta)}\tan\left(
\frac{\pi}{2}\left(
1 - \frac{2i - 2\eta - 1}{n}
\right)\right)\right),
$$
where  the 'optimum' value of $\eta$ depends on $n$, but seems to
consist of a constant term of about $0.348$ plus a small positive
term of order about $n^{-2}$. Like the $u_i$ themselves, the
approximate values sum exactly to $1$, thanks to this identity:
$$
\tan\theta = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}
- \frac{(2i-1)\pi}{2n} + \frac{\theta}{n}\right)
\quad \left(n \geqslant 1, \ \theta \ne k\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}\right).
$$
(Proof: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346368) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1094930).)

Leaving aside the problem of explaining the closeness of this
approximation, the question I am asking here is whether, for all $n$
(the value of $n$ is absent from the notation I am using, but we
could instead use a notation like $u_i^{(n)}$), we have:
$$
u_1 > u_2 > \cdots > u_n.
$$
Equivalently, $\sin^{-1}(x_i) - \sin^{-1}(s_{i-1}) >
\sin^{-1}(x_{i+1}) - \sin^{-1}(s_i)$, i.e.:
$$
x_i\sqrt{1 - s_{i-1}^2} - s_{i-1}\sqrt{1 - x_i^2} >
x_{i+1}\sqrt{1 - s_i^2} - s_i\sqrt{1 - x_{i+1}^2}
\quad (1 \leqslant i < n).
$$